# Subscriptions not allowed on APIs/API Products in the state: PROTOTYPED

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm new to wso2 api manager. I have created a aws API gateway. When I try to run that using try out  in the publisher page,  I get this error from logs:

Subscriptions not allowed on APIs/API Products in the state: PROTOTYPED
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an API prototype for the purpose of early promotion and testing. You can deploy a new API or a new version of an existing API as a prototype. It gives subscribers an early implementation of the API that they can try out without a subscription or monetization, and in-turn the subscribers can provide feedback to improve the API. After a period of time, the publishers can make changes that the users request and publish the API.
Therefore if you have published an API with a prototype state, you don't need to subscribe to that API to test that.
[1]. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/design-api/mock-api/deploy-and-test-mock-apis/#step-2-publish-a-prototyped-api